# Extracting bounding box from the polygon geometry in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, extents

Suppose I have a geometry like below:

POLYGON((8744004.877693035 1958621.044138512,8744013.76051175 1958620.4469742286,8744019.582863515 1958613.8781671105,8744018.98569923 1958611.3402189056,8744015.178776924 1958611.7880921182,8744009.953589443 1958614.4753313938,8744008.3860332 1958618.3568992366,8744004.803047499 1958619.103354591,8744004.877693035 1958621.044138512))

I want to get bounding box for above geometry like any geometry `minX,minY,maxX,maxY` in OpenLayers.

I am using below line of code to get geometry:

```
geometrydraw.on('drawend',function(event){              
    olmap.removeInteraction(draw);
    createdProjectFeature=event.feature;
    var format = new ol.format.WKT();            
    projectGeometry = format.writeGeometry(event.feature.getGeometry());
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have a look at docs: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon-Polygon.html

Comment: ya like i am using openlayers map by using below line i am getting 
    geometrydraw.on('drawend',function(event){    
    olmap.removeInteraction(draw);
    createdProjectFeature=event.feature;
    var format = new ol.format.WKT();
    projectGeometry=format.writeGeometry(event.feature.getGeometry());

Comment: is there any way i can extract like any api function i can call to extract the bouding box.?

Comment: Edit your question and include your code of what you have tried so far in the body of the question.

Comment: Since you already have geometry, you can use `getExtent` method, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Geometry-Geometry.html

Comment: Thank you i am aslo using the same getExtent function calling over getGeometry are you sure that this will return boundingbox values.It is returning four values of extents.

Comment: How can cross check the bounding box values are correct location over map any online resource to verify that?

Comment: Here: https://boundingbox.klokantech.com/